# Python HTTPserver Error 501: Unsupported Method 'DELETE'

Tags: python, sockets, http, error-handling, http-delete

I am trying to solve this example and I am having a hard time resolving the error I get. Here it is in fullest:
Error response. Error code: 501. Message: Unsupported method ('DELETE'). Error code explanation: HTTPStatusNOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation. Here is server file code below:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
names_dict = {'john': 'smith',
              'david': 'jones',
              'michael': 'johnson',
              'chris': 'lee',
              'vinicius': 'jad'}


class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.log_message("Incoming GET request...")
        try:
            name = parse_qs(self.path[2:])['name'][0]
        except:
            self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Incorrect parameters provided')
            self.log_message("Incorrect parameters provided")
            return

        if name in names_dict.keys():
            self.send_response_to_client(200, names_dict[name])
        else:
            self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Name not found')
            self.log_message("Name not found")

    def do_POST(self):
        self.log_message('Incoming POST request...')
        data = parse_qs(self.path[2:])
        try:
            names_dict[data['name'][0]] = data['last_name'][0]
            self.send_response_to_client(200, names_dict)
        except KeyError:
            self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Incorrect parameters provided')
            self.log_message("Incorrect parameters provided")

    def do_DELETE(self):
        self.log_message("Incoming DELETE request...")
        name = parse_qs(self.path[2:])
        try:
            if name in names_dict.keys():
                del names_dict[name['name']]
                self.send_response_to_client(200, names_dict[name])
            else:
                self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Name not found')
                self.log_message("Name not found")
        except:
            self.send_response_to_client(404, 'Incorrect parameters provided')
            self.log_message("Incorrect parameters provided")
            return

    def send_response_to_client(self, status_code, data):
        self.send_response(status_code)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(str(data).encode())


server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
http_server = HTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

And here is client file code below.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/", params={"name": 'michael'})
print("Request method: GET, \
    Response status_code: {}, Response data: {}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
                  params={'name': 'peter', 'last_name': 'peterson'})
print("Request method: POST, \
    Response status_code: {}, Response data: {}".format(r.status_code, r.text))

r = requests.delete("http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
                    params={'name': 'vinicius'})
print("Request method: DELETE, \
    Response status_code: {}, Response data: {}".format(r.status_code, r.text))
```

The point of DELETE function is to delete the given name from the dictionary. Any thoughts on how I can resolve this issue? Cheers

Comment: Looking at the API documentation, do_DELETE doesn't seem to be a supported method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Comment: For support for more HTTP methods, I'd recommend Flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods